# Setting a generic typed optional map with an object with a strongly typed field

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write code to register strongly typed data loaders, however I'm having trouble with typescript to get the map to set correctly. In the below example, `M` is the service map and `k` is the list of services with a field type which is a definite value of `E`. However, when I try to assign an instance to the map, it gives me an error saying i'm trying to assign to undefined. Not sure where to go from here.

```
enum E {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
}

interface I<T extends E> {
  type: T;
}

type J<T> = T extends E ? I<T> : never;
export type K = J<E>;

const M: { [T in E]?: I<T> } = {};
const k: K[] = [];

k.forEach(
  <T extends E>(i: I<T>) => {
    M[i.type] = i;
    // ERROR
    // Type 'I<T>' is not assignable to type '{ a?: I<E.A> | undefined; b?: I<E.B> | undefined; }[T]'.
    //  Type 'I<T>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  });
```

Comment: Looks like another candidate for [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); the compiler can't verify this as safe.  You'll probably just want to use a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Lw69GW) and move on, in my experience

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a limitation of the TypeScript compiler, or possibly a combination of multiple such limitations.  The relevant issues I see here are:

- [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) (support `extends_oneof` generic constraint)) and [microsoft/TypeScript#25879](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25879) (support generic indexes into non-generic mapped types, exactly your use case above):

  Currently there is no way to say that a type parameter constrained to a union (like your `T extends E` above) can only take on a *single* element of the union at a time.  Right now, `T extends E` means that `T` can be specified with any one of the *four* following types: `never`, `E.A`, `E.B`, or `E.A | E.B` (which is just `E`).  If it were possible to tell the compiler that `T` may be `E.A`, *or* it may be `E.B`, but it can't be the union of them, then *perhaps* the compiler could realize that your assignment works for each one of those and accept both of them.

  But this is not what happens.  `T` may be specified with `E.A | E.B`, and so  `M[i.type] = i` has to work for that case.  Your generic callback function might therefore as well be changed to its non-generic version

  ```
  k.forEach((i: I<E>) => { M[i.type] = i; }); // error!
  // --------------------> ~~~~~~~~~
  // Type 'I<E>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
  ```

  for all the good it's doing.  This version also errors, for other reasons:
- [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) (support correlated types), [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) (support distributive control flow analysis):

  Let's assume that `i` is of the type `I<E.A> | I<E.B>`. The compiler is, unfortunately, unable to perform the higher-order reasoning necessary to see that `M[i.type] = i` is acceptable.  On the left-hand side of the assignment, `M[i.type]` is seen to be of the type `M[E.A] | M[E.B]`.  But because you are trying to *assign* a value to that type, the compiler requires that the assigned value be of the *intersection* of those types instead of the *union*.  This was [introduced in TypeScript 3.5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) via [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) as a way of improving safety.  So `M[i.type]` on the left-hand side is seen as type `M[E.A] & M[E.B]`, which is `(I<E.A> | undefined) & (I<E.B> | undefined)`.  Since `I<E.A> & I<E.B>` is `never`, this reduces to just `undefined`.  The type of `i` on the right is `I<E.A> | I<E.B>`, which is not assignable to `undefined`, and so there's an error.

  This error would make sense if, for example, we had two values, `i` and `j`, both of type `I<E.A> | I<E.B>` and tried to assign `M[i.type] = j`;.  The compiler would rightfully complain that since `j` cannot possibly be *both* `I<E.A>` *and* `I<E.B>`, then it's not safe to assign it to `M[i.type]`, because maybe `i.type !== j.type`.  Because the compiler is only paying attention to the *types* in the obviously-safe `M[i.type] = i`, it cannot currently tell the difference between that and the obviously-unsafe `M[i.type] = j`.

  What we'd *like* to tell the compiler is that the types of `M[i.type]` and `i` are *correlated* to each other: even though they are both union types, it is impossible for `M[i.type]` to be of type `I<E.A>` while `i` is of type `I<E.B>`.  But this is not currently possible.

---

So what can you do as a workaround?  The *easiest* thing you can do (and probably the right thing to do) is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). *You* know what you're doing is safe, so just tell the compiler not to worry about it.  The simplest assertion is to toss the `any` grenade in there:

```
k.forEach(
  (i) => {
    M[i.type] = i as any;
  });
```

There are some slightly less unsafe assertions you can use:

```
k.forEach(
  <T extends E>(i: I<T>) => {
    M[i.type] = i as any as (typeof M)[T];
  });
```

where you preserve the generic callback and tell the compiler that the assignment is safe, or:

```
k.forEach(
  <T extends E>(i: I<T>) => {
    (M as { [K in T]?: I<K> })[i.type] = i;
  });
```

where you preserve the generic callback and tell the compiler that `M` can be treated as if it only had a key of type `T`.  This one is probably my favorite because it comes closest to expressing what you're trying to do.

The other possible workaround is to explicitly narrow `i` to `I<E.A>` and `I<E.B>` in turn, at which point the compiler's control flow analysis can take over:

```
k.forEach(i => i.type === E.A ?
  M[i.type] = i :
  M[i.type] = i
)
```

this is redundant, obviously, and not what you'd want to do.  But it does show that the compiler could in principle understand that `M[i.type] = i` is safe, if it were possible to tell the compiler to pretend that such an enumeration of cases were performed (as in microsoft/TypeScript#25051).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeAoKUCCUC8UDkBDbANMlAEKY4BGhiAvoogJYgAuwATgGa4DGwUAkgB4AKlGAAPViAAmAZ1gA+BMWYBPAA7AAXFGEBuWvTWaoAKRFKsoiVLmwoAfgEWoOkMABu7AxPUB7NmYoYz4AaXJzGAUDRG4-EFkggFkdeCgAbVEmWABdBx0hYSUacngaAziEoIBrHVD0nPIGmOqAOg4AmB4ACwAKYhExSVA7KN6GAosASkwlJBQUJPSGVpDGrAYDFBoplvbOnv6UccmomYw54kXl1Y1gdahN4h29jrYu7j7icfPLhaglis1uQGFBcPJ3F42FsoC96Ig2m8Pl8UIMbCN5GMJs4ir9lP9AbdNA9QeCwSBVGD5L0Qn4OACppkcjC4Qj9u9DgNrMMZJiFCccQo8fMFr0klSEBlwtlhHlJqFioygXcSSzdvREQdPuNZo8iXwMIbYK10A5iITgRtXOabpbHogpvCgA)